# Animation not performed for Z transition on Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, css-transitions

I am trying to create a simple animation on the Z axis for an HTML element using the following CSS code:

```
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1000ms ease 500ms;
-webkit-transform: perspective(100px) translate3d(0px, 0px, -20px);
```

The problem is that the animation is not performed for the Z axis (just a sudden jump when the animation should end). If I switch the axis, for example X, then the animation is performed correctly.

**Edit**: If I mix the axes, then the animation is only performed for the X and Y axis, and when the animation ends, the element is moved to the correct position on the Z axis (with a sudden jump).

The same CSS code when used in FireFox (without the vendor prefixes) works correctly, the element is animated on every axis, including Z.

Is this a Chrome specific issue, or am I using the transform elements incorrectly?

**Edit2**: Created a JSFiddle with a sample code [(link)](http://jsfiddle.net/xpR2n/)

Comment: make your transform values before transition explicit. maybe it helps.

Comment: there are none, I just add the above CSS elements to a div in the page and then refresh to see the transition.

Comment: @DanOvidiuBoncut I've tried to add a transform which resets all to 0 before I add the transition, and the same behavior doesn't change: the X and Y axes animate properly, but the Z axis remains stationary until the animation ends.

Comment: can you add the content of your element and the css to a jsfiddle?
as far as i know the transitions are ussulay started by an event :hover, click, focus, adding a class, but not by a refresh. why not trying to make an animation?

Comment: @DanOvidiuBoncut added a JSFiddle with an example in the question form above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perspective is a separate thing, not part of transform.

```
-webkit-transform: perspective(100px) translate3d(0px, 0px, -20px);
```

should be:

```
-webkit-perspective: 100px;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, -20px);
```

Also, you need to define perspective on something surrounding the element.

I've surrounded your element with an element called `#stage`, the set the perspective on that instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/xpR2n/2/

Shows what to do.

Comment: If I set the perspective separate, then the Z axis doesn't animate at all (or isn't affected by the perspective as the size doesn't change).

Comment: Yep, it did the trick. It is strange though that this works in Firefox. Thanks!

Comment: Firefox supports plain old transform, rather than -moz- or -webkit-.